# Way to connect to Azure Keyvault using MSI from a java application running locally

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I am using REST call to connect to azure keyvault from my app deployed on azure VM. Code below:

//    msiEndpoint: http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net

```
URL url = new URL (msiEndpoint);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod(Keyvault.HTTPS_METHOD_GET);
con.setRequestProperty("Metadata", "true");
if (Keyvault.HTTPS_SUCCESS_CODE != con.getResponseCode()) {
throw new Exception("Error calling managed identity token endpoint.");
} else {
InputStream responseStream = con.getInputStream();  
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Token token = objectMapper.readValue(responseStream, Token.class);
accessToken = token.getAccess_token();
}
```

to retrieve the value accessToken where Token is an inner private static class with variables:

```
private String access_token = null;
private String expires_in = null;
private String token_type = null;
```

This code when deployed on azure VM connects fine and is able to retrieve secrets. But when I try to run it locally it cannot connect to keyvault in absence of MSI. I am using a user assigned identity here with which I would like to know how to establish the connection here. or any other way of doing it from code itself.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score -1):

Azure Managed Service identity either system assigned or user assigned are applicable to resources/applications that are running on azure.

For local development you would need to use the azure keyvault URL and credentials to access keys or secrets on azure keyvault.

[Azure managed service identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

[Azure key vault libraries for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/keyvault?view=azure-java-stable)

Comment: You can also run az cli locally to get tokens as the current user. It can be invoked from Java code as well.